# Put a string into an array

Tags: php

I have a string that contains this:

`array(a=1, b=2, c=array(ca=23, cb=45),d=array(da=342, db=array(dba=3154, dbb=8746), dc=765),e=8)`

Now, I need to create an array from the contents of this string. I tried it this way:

```
$arrValues = array();
$arrValues = $strVar;
var_dump($arrValues);
```

But of course, as was to be expected, this just gives you an array with 1 item of type string, and the whole shebang in it.

Any tips?

Comment: What is `$strVar`? That initial literal?

Comment: @GrantThomas From the OP, I'd assume the string `array(a=1, b=2, c=array(ca=23, cb=45),d=array(da=342, db=array(dba=3154, dbb=8746), dc=765),e=8)`.

Comment: Yes indeed, $strVar is the variable that contains the "arraystring"

Comment: How "safe" would this string be? If it's quite safe, you can `eval()` it after some modification.

Comment: @Borniet Where do you have this string from? Is it something you're putting into a database/file yourself, and could you essentially use [`serialize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) or [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to save the data instead, and then use [`unserialize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) and [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to get the array back?

Comment: Well, it is for an internal tool, and I would be the one to put the string in there, so it is "safe" :-)

Comment: @h2ooooooo I input this string myself. It is the return I get from a function, and I copy/paste it back. I have no control over the output of this function however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I say anything about using `eval()`, [**read this stackoverflow post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php).

As Yazmat mentioned, you could use [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) if you're very sure that nobody could inject code into this, and use a regex of `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s*=\s*` replaced with `"$1" =>` to change your code to be PHP array compliant:

```
<?php
    $strVar = 'array(a=1, b=2, c=array(ca=23, cb=45),d=array(da=342, db=array(dba=3154, dbb=8746), dc=765),e=8)';
    $arrValues = array();

    $phpCompliantStrVar = preg_replace('/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s*=\s*/', '"$1" => ', $strVar) . ';';
    //string(157) "array("a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => array("ca" => 23, "cb" => 45),"d" => array("da" => 342, "db" => array("dba" => 3154, "dbb" => 8746), "dc" => 765),"e" => 8);"

    //Beware of the evilness that eval can cause! It will suck out your soul if overdone.
    eval('$arrValues = ' . $phpCompliantStrVar);

    print_r($arrValues);
    /*
        Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 2
            [c] => Array
                (
                    [ca] => 23
                    [cb] => 45
                )

            [d] => Array
                (
                    [da] => 342
                    [db] => Array
                        (
                            [dba] => 3154
                            [dbb] => 8746
                        )

                    [dc] => 765
                )

            [e] => 8
        )
    */
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/kR0q2tFV)

**Current limitations:**

- It will ONLY work if your values in the array are all numbers - else you need to change the regex.

Comment: This one does the trick! As said above, the tool will be used internal, probably even only by me. So the input is safe.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) but it is not recommanded unless you are sure of what will contain the string (it may cause security issues)

**Edit :**

It seems that your array is not in the syntaxe of a php array, you will need to reformat it.

Comment: Doesn't look like valid array syntax to be eval'd imho.

Comment: I'd say to `str_replace` the `=` with `=>` but eval + arbitrary replacing without even checking if the `=` is part of a string is a little overkill. Oh it also lacks keys' quoting, never mind.

Comment: even replacing `=` with `=>` and string keys with `"string_key"` doesn't successfully `eval()` this array. Thoughts?